# Android:showing same result when choosing location provider

Tags: android, gps, location, wifi, cellular-network

I am trying to get current location using `GPS`,`Cellular Network` or `WiFi`.I am giving criteria to choose best provider. But It is always showing `GPS` is best provider. It is ok when i am outside and `GPS` signal is strong but it is not true when i am indoor or `GPS` signal is poor.
The criteria are

```
  Criteria criteria  = new Criteria();
  criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
  criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
  criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
  criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
  criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
  String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

What is the solution? Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting accuracy criteria to `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` will always give you `GPS_PROVIDER` if available in your device. On the other hand setting `Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE` gives you `NETWORK_PROVIDER` if available. It's good practice to start both and use `NETWORK_PROVIDER` first as it may take few minutes to get a fix from `GPS`.

See [android-protips-location](http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/) for the location best-practices for reducing latency and battery consumption.

These also may help:

[Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate)

[Android Protips: Advanced Topics for Expert Android App Developers](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-protips-advanced-topics-for-expert-android-app-developers.html)